# How do I return information from an API? C#

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I've made a simple API to interface with a SQL server and I have been able to use Postman and my web browser to access it, but when I go to access it from a console application, I am unable to do so. All I want to do in the API is to check if a username is located in a database and if it is, return true. I've tried putting the BaseAddress inside of the `GetAsync()` Function, to no avail, as well as removing and re-adding the `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders`.

API:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Moving_App_Web_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("MovingApp/Users")]
    [ApiController]

    public class MovingAppController : ControllerBase
    {
        List<string> Username;

        private readonly ILogger<MovingAppController> _logger;
        public MovingAppController(ILogger<MovingAppController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Username = new List<string>();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string GetMovingApp()
        {
           return "Hello World";
        }
        
        [HttpGet("{username}")]
        public string UserCheck(string username)
        {
            bool UsernameExist;

            ServerConnection Connection = new ServerConnection();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.connString);

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(UserID) FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count != 0) UsernameExist = true;
            else UsernameExist = false;

            /*SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Username.Add((string)dr["Username"]);
            }*/
            conn.Close();
            return UsernameExist.ToString();
        }
```

Console App:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           CallWebAPIAsync();
        }

        static void CallWebAPIAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44340/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                
                string response = client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:44340/MovingApp/Users/User1").Result;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IT WORKS");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I get when I run the ConsoleApp are:

```
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.CallWebAPIAsync() in C:\Users\Computer\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 23
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Computer\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 12

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Comment: As a guess, if you have a solution with 2 startup csprojs....one as webapi, one as client, but an artificial client "thread sleep" delay .. on the client.  You gotta give the time for the webapi to fully start.  alternatively, you can use POSTMAN as a client.... then after you know POSTMAN calls work, you can code them up in c# "clientlibrary"

Comment: Are you sure the API is on HTTP and not HTTPS? Also, in the `GetStringAsync` method you only need to pass the relative path since you already specified the base URL: `client.GetStringAsync("/MovingApp/Users/User1")`

Comment: Oh, and consider do a proper await instead of .Result too.

Comment: @granadaCoder, I used the Code Snippets tool from Postman to get c# code for the call using RestSharp, and the command executed, without errors but it didnt return any response that could be written the console. ```var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44340/MovingApp/Users/User2");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("text/plain", "",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);``` Is this what you meant?

Comment: What I mean is.  "Can I get it working in Postman??" When that answer is "yes", THEN you can go "code it up".  But it has to work in postman first.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732289/net-core-httpclient-bug-socketexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-c) link. I am pretty sure it's the same thing you're going through.

Comment: @granadaCoder it works in Postman, but my attempts to "code it up" haven't worked

Comment: So I think that the reason it isn't working/returning a result, is because my computer doesn't have a valid SSL certificate that the code can trust. I'm trying now to host it on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Did you put in the Thread.Sleep(20000); . in the client code? BEFORE the call to "CallWebAPIAsync();" ..  20 seconds is a little "too much", but you should start there.  You need to give a little time for the webapi to start up.